# Como usar o carousel do bootstrap em um tema do wordpress

Tags: jquery, html5, wordpress, css3, bootstrap

Fiz um tema simples em wordpress e estou usando esse tipo de js:

```
(function($) {

    console.log("teste");
    $('.carousel').carousel();

})(jQuery);
```

e esse html:

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

e o functions.php tá assim:

```
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'); 
  wp_enqueue_script('popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js');

  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

No functions.php do tema o Bootstrap tá incluido e funcionando, o sistema de grids dele tá funcionando,  só que o carousel não é iniciado e recebo o erro no console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
```

Tambem verifiquei na aba sources do chrome e dei um CTRL+P e consigo ver o bootrap.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois a função está sendo executada logo depois de ser criada (antes mesmo do *script* do *Bootstrap* ser — completamente — carregado). O ideal é utilizar

```
jQuery.ready(function($) {
    console.log("teste");
    $('.carousel').carousel();
})
```

Pois dessa forma, seu código será executado somente após o carregamento da página.